# Angular sibling ngInit method not call after data update

Tags: javascript, angular6, parent-child

I have two siblings in a parent, and data for a sibling is being updated, data is updated, but

```
ngOnInit(){}
```

not called.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ctf2z?file=src/app/child2/child2.component.ts

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Found "ngOnChange", worked

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ngOnInit` with `ngOnChange` as follows:

```
export class Child2Component implements OnChange {
  @Input() data:any;
  @Output() onEmit:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnChange() {
    if(this.data.test1%2){
      this.data.test2 += this.data.test1
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the lifecycle, and found ngDoCheck,